# You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

How do I change the Firebase project in my cli?

When I run `firebase init`, it says:

```
Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Are you ready to proceed? (Y/n)
```

It never asks on which project do I need to upload. How can I link my other project?

Comment: This first reminder is that the CLI will create `firebase.json` in the current directory. Only after that will it prompt you to select a project. Did you hit enter/press `Y`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will look in the current directory *and all parent directories* for a file called `.firebaserc` that defines which project is being used in this directory structure.  If you run `firebase init` and encounter the message "You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory", that means one of these `.firebaserc` files was found, and it's going to re-initialize this project.

If you no longer want the original project, just delete the `.firebaserc` file.  Or, find another directory to run `firebase init` that isn't within another project's space.

Comment: This is a brand new project and there is no firebaserc in it

Comment: As I suggested in my answer, you should also look in all the parent directories of the one where you're running the init.  Did you do that?

Comment: I think yes may be because when I run firebase login, it said already logged in, now how do I find in which project that file is kept

Comment: This is a different project and firebase should ask me about this project, isn't it

Comment: You can't have a Firebase project live inside a folder on another project.

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand, this is a new ionic project :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `firebase init` with flag `--project <projectId>`

Comment: This didn't work (when paired with `--only firestore`, didn't try without it). I ended up manually changing the `"default"` project in `.firebaserc`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` file from the project directory.
It works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I create multiple project in Projects folder. Already try delete file from projects `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` but not working.

**Finally Follow the bellow steps: It works properly**
You can try this command to set new project from your Firebase project list

```
firebase use --add
```

Answer the question: What alias do you want to use for this project? (e.g. staging) "Write something"

And take step from start

```
firebase init
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting `.firebaserc` did not work for me. I also had to delete `firestore.json`.